# How to restrict the input type "number" to powers of 2?

Tags: javascript, html, input, numbers

I want to restrict `<input type=number>` to accept only powers of 2, like 1,2,4,8,16 ...

Is there a pure HTML solution for this, or I should use javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll definitely have to use scripts... there is no static solution in html to detect that pattern....... however

if you want to match with a static or dynamic string pattern then in html you have choice of using 'pattern' attribute for some regex patterns.. for example...

you can use `<input type=text pattern='^\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d$' >` (just for explanation although it will accept 99/99/9999 as date which is incorrect).
to force user to input date in pattern of dd/MM/yyyy you can know more about regex on http://regexone.com...
regex stands for regular expressions

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'll need javascript for that. There's no pure HTML solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I will post my javascript method for doing this (as the answers said it is impossible with pure HTML)

```
<input id="koko" type="number" min=1 onchange="applyChange(validate(this))">
 <span id='note' hidden><font color=red>Please enter powers of two</font> 

</span>
<script>
var saver=1;
function applyChange(num)
{
 document.getElementById('koko').value=num;
}
function validate(input)
{
 document.getElementById('note').hidden=true;
 var number=input.value;
 if(Number.isInteger(Math.log2(number)))
     return (saver=number);
 else
  {
  document.getElementById('note').hidden=false;
   return saver;
 }
}
</script>
```